# Redirect to an id with javascript and smooth effect

Tags: javascript

**Question**
Is it possible redirect from one page to another to `section id="pro"` with smooth effect?
For example, when I'm on the site '`about`' I can not redirect to '`work`' to section pro.

**Code**
Nawigation

```
<li><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#pro">Work</a></li>
```

**js file**

```
$(function () {

    $("a.smooth-scroll").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = 'http://localhost/photo_gallery/index.html';
        var section_id = $(this).attr("href");  
        var count = url + section_id;
        alert(count);   
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(count).offset().top - 64
        }, 1250, "easeInOutExpo");

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) to `html` element via css.

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```